# Facebook php sdk session logic

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How i maintain a session cookie in my facebook app?
currently all of my pages have the code below:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'myid',
  'secret' => 'mysecret',
  'cookie' => true,
));


$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                          'fbconnect' => 0,
                                          'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,email',
                                          'next' => 'register.php',
                                          'cancel_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=MYAPPID&perms' ));
}

if (!$me){ print("<html><head>");
print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">function redirect(){ top.location.href = \"");

print($loginUrl);
print("\"; }</script></head>");
print("<body onload=\"redirect();\">Please wait...</body></html>"); exit(); }
```

This is wrong as i understand, i'm getting a new session each time a user navigate to a different page in my canvas. Do i need to use request? if so how do i accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the PHP SDK to fetch the user session, and that's okay.  The PHP SDK is smart enough to set and utilize a cookie on the user which holds their session information - so you're not 'fetching' anything new from Facebook on every page load.  You do need the redirect for install on every page just in case your user session does time out, or if the user uninstalls your app mid-use, or gets a direct link into a page of your application without being an installed user.

To make your code a little cleaner, you could move all the code to fetch the session & capture the installation from the user to a single script, and include it at the top of each page in your application.  Then you don't have all that floating around, and you can easily change/tweak it when and if you need to.

**edit**:  If your users are losing a session every time they navigate to a different page within your application, the user's browser might be blocking the cookie that the FB PHP SDK is setting because it's in an iframe.  You probably need to set a P3P Policy header in your application, also, and this often fixes that problem.

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Comment: But users lose the session when they navigate to a different page

Comment: Added more to my answer, that might help (:

Comment: Thanks for the info on the P3P policy header. This had caused a day of undue stress for us.